# Pass a model to controller from radio button

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to pass a model from a radio button? I have seen examples but these are passing simple types like `strings` and `ids` however, if I were to do something a little more complex is this possible? For example, if I had models that looked like:

```
public class RestaurantMenuViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<RestaurantMenu> Menu { get; set; }
}

public class RestaurantMenu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Course { get; set; 
}
```

I can bind this in my view visually, however I want to be able to pass the selected item to the controller not just a primitive field (like id or course). Is this possible?

I want the below action to be called but want to pass the full model back to the controller.

```
    public ActionResult Update(RestaurantMenu menu)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("OK");
    }
```

Comment: Short answer is no. A radio button group only passes back the value of its selected button (not a complex object). But why would you want to anyway? just pass back the selected `Id` value and if you need the `RestaurantMenu` object, get it from the db again.

Comment: That was the approach but was hoping not to hit the DB again. Thats fine though, if its not possible  I have an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can give this a try.
Create an object array, to store different types of data coming from your radiobuttons, then convert it to a Model;

```
 object[] RestaurantMenuArray = new object[1];
 object[0] = RestaurantMenu.Id;
 object[1] = RestaurantMenu.Course;
 RestaurantMenuArray.Select(array => new RestaurantMenu { Id = array[0], 
 Course = array[1] });
```